# to execute a file using javascript and display the output of executed file

Tags: javascript

Is it possible through javascript to read a file and exexcute it.
for eg if we have written code for button it should read and display actual button as output.

Comment: Looks like a bad pattern design.

Answer (score 1):

You may use *eval* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

However this is not a good practice and you should avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for jQuery `$.load` http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

In the above code, the `load` method will load the test.html file and put it contents with in the div with id `result` for e.g.

```
<div id="result"></div>
```